# Why is iterating a group different than iterating a collection in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

In the query below it is easy to see how we are basically looping through sampleOrders and evaluating each order i.e. we can access the properties of ord:

```
var o = (
            from ord in sampleOrders
            select ord.Quantity
```

In the query below we are grouping orders by product into orderGroups.  orderGroups is conceptually a "list of lists" where each list has a key and a property which contains associated orders.  The preceeding description is very loose of course - the point is that if I iterate the collection I would expect to receive an object with a key property and a property that contains the orders.  This behavior seems to be consistent with the first query above.  But in fact each group is an order.  It appears by iterating the list of groups that we bypass the group itself and in fact iterate each order.
Why is this grouping behavior different from the behavior in the first query above?

```
var o = (
            from ord in sampleOrders
            group ord by ord.Product into orderGroups
            from grp in orderGroups
            select grp  // grp is an order, not a group of orders
```

BTW, Please note I am not asking how to access the groups..... my question is related to the concept and the syntax.
Here is how to access each group.... I am not asking how to do this:

```
var o = (
            from ord in sampleOrders
            group ord by ord.Product into orderGroups
            select new {orderGroups.Key, SumQty=orderGroups.Sum(x => x.Quantity)}
```

Edit: Working example per request

```
public static void LinqTest()
    { 
        List<Order> sampleOrders = new List<Order>()
        {
            new Order{Product="A", Quantity = 3},
            new Order{Product="A", Quantity = 4},
            new Order{Product="B", Quantity = 5},
            new Order{Product="C", Quantity = 6},
        };


        var orders =
            from ord in sampleOrders
            group ord by ord.Product into orderGroups
            select orderGroups;

        foreach (var grp in orders)      // here is the outer list
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product: " + grp.Key.ToString());

            // here is the inner list hence the term "list of lists" 
            // it is in fact a hierarchical object however this fact is irrelelvent to my question
            // 
            foreach (Order ord in grp)   
                Console.WriteLine("Qty: " + ord.Quantity);


        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("following listing is grouped orders but we see each order not groups");

        var orders2 =
         from ord in sampleOrders
         group ord by ord.Product into orderGroups
         from grp in orderGroups
         select grp;

        foreach(Order ord2 in orders2)
            Console.WriteLine("Product: " + ord2.Product);  // each item returned is an order not a group of orders


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Order
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is another stab at clarifying my question:
In the first query above "from x in listOfx" gives you an object, x, which is the same object that listOfx is composed of.

In the group query, "from x in listOfxGroups" gives you an object which is *different* than the objects that compose listOfxGroups.  listOfxGroups is in fact a list of groups... but when we iterate it we get x not "group of x".

Comment: "grp is an order, not a group of orders" - no it's not. It's a group, because it's an element of `group ord by ord.Product into orderGroups`. It's not really clear what you're asking, to be honest - it would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Actually, `grp` is an order. `group ord by ord.Product` would produce an `IGrouping<>`, but `into orderGroups` makes `orderGroups` an `IEnumerable<Order>`, so doing a `from grp in` on that makes `grp` an `Order`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Nearly - I think it makes `orderGroups` an `IGrouping<string, Order>` which then implements `IEnumerable<Order>`... which is then flattened by the follow-on `from`. I agree with your conclusion but not *quite* the journey. Apologies for the incorrect statement to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for the correction. `group ord by ord.Product` makes an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>`, so `orderGroups` is an `IGrouping<,>`, which is also an `IEnumerable<Order>`. Putting a `from` on that makes each value an `Order`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Exactly. Not sure why I had a mental block on it to start with...

Comment: @Sam: Your confusion is simply because `orderGroups` isn't a sequence of groups... it's a range variable of a *single* group.

Comment: @Sam: Jon is right. In other words, it would probably clear up your confusion immensely if you named it `orderGroup` (singular) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        from ord in sampleOrders
        group ord by ord.Product into orderGroups
        from grp in orderGroups
        select grp
```

At a glance, one might think that this translates to this:

```
sampleOrders.GroupBy(ord => ord.Product)
    .Select(grp => grp); // grp is an `IGrouping<,>`
```

But in actuality, it translates to this:

```
sampleOrders.GroupBy(ord => ord.Product)
    .SelectMany(orderGroup => orderGroup); // orderGroup is an `IGrouping<,>`
    .Select(grp => grp); // grp is an Order
```

This is how LINQ statements are translated: after the initial `from` keyword, any remaining `from`s produce a SelectMany. For example:

> A query expression with a second from clause followed by a select clause
>
> ```
> from x1 in e1
> from x2 in e2
> select v
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> ( e1 ) . SelectMany( x1 => e2 , ( x1 , x2 ) => v )
> ```
>
> [C# 5 language spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), section 7.16.2.4

```
from a in x
from b in a
select b
```

Now, the lambda expression in `SelectMany` must return an `IEnumerable<T>` (which it does, because `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` is also an `IEnumerable<TValue>`), and SelectMany flattens out all of the `IEnumerable<T>`s into one big `IEnumerable<T>`, which means that the individual items in it are `Order`s, in this case.

#### Update

Just to help clarify, imagine the following:

```
var orderGroups =              // orderGroups is plural: IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>
    from ord in sampleOrders
    group ord by ord.Product;
var o =
    from orderGroup in orderGroups // orderGroup is singular: IGrouping<,>
    from item in orderGroup        // `item` instead of `grp`
    select item;
```

This is effectively what you produce with your `into` clause, but with different variable names.

```
var o = 
        from ord in sampleOrders
        group ord by ord.Product into orderGroup
        from item in orderGroup
        select item;               // item is an order, not a group of orders
```

Comment: >>After the initial from keyword, any remaining froms produce a SelectMany.  This is true for any query?? Where is this documented?

Comment: Your answer addresses my question directly btw...  >>>Which makes sense, because the following pattern would produce a SelectMany as well, right?  This is no doubt true but I do not understand why it works this way.

Comment: @Sam: I simplified things somewhat. Most tutorials online focus on teaching the *behavior* of multiple from clauses, but don't go into details on its implementation. However, I added a reference to the C# spec (which Jon Skeet reads for fun), where you can find many more details.

Comment: If you do check out the C# spec, be sure to also check 7.16.2.1, which deals with the treatment of "group by ... into ..."

Answer (score 2):

> orderGroups is conceptually a "list of lists"

No, it's not.  It's conceptually a *single* group, not a group of groups.  When you say:

```
from grp in orderGroups
```

`grp` now represents one item in the group (in this case, an order), not one group, as you're iterating all of the items in one group.

If you selected out the group, *then* the entire query would represent a list of groups (or a list of lists).

```
var listOfGroups = from order in sampleOrders
    group order by order.Product into orderGroup
    select orderGroup;
```

Comment: It is not a single group.  It is a collection. It is not a collections of items that are grouped.  It is a collection of the GROUPS of items that are grouped.  The collections is composed of objects which contain a key property and a property which is itself a collection, and that collection is composed of the objects which are grouped.

Comment: @Sam No, you are not correct.  That's what I'm telling you.  Your assumption about what that variable contains is incorrect.  The range variable represents a single group, not a group of groups.  You'd need to select out that single group as the result of your query to have the resulting variable represent a sequence of groups.  The tests that you have performed have in fact confirmed this statement of mine, as it is the only way for the code snippets that you have to do what they do.

Comment: please see the working code example that iterates orderGroups and prints the "Key" property (no such property exists on the Order class).

Comment: @Sam Yes, and there you're iterating `orders`, which *is* a list of groups.  `orderGroups` is a single group, and when you project each group as the item of the query the resulting query represents a list of groups, in just the same way that if you wrote `select 1`; you've have a list of `int`s, not an `int` as the result.

Comment: yes, my query is ...select orderGroups. So in very practical terms we are assigning orderGroups to orders which means orders = orderGroups.  Now, when I iterate orderGroups in the SECOND query in my edit, I get orders........ not groups of orders which I expect to see.

Comment: @Sam No, just as I said before, what you select out in your query is not exactly what the results of your query are.  The results of your query are *a sequence of whatever you `select`*.  In this case you select `orderGroups`, so `orders` is a *sequence of whatever `orderGroups` is*.  `orders` is a sequence of groups, therefore `orderGroups` must be a single group, if selecting it creates a sequence of groups.  Do you think that in your first query, `from ord in sampleOrders select ord.Quantity` that `ord.Quantity` represents a sequence of quantities? Does `ord` represent a sequence of orders?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at Microsoft's documenation for the [group caluse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx).

*The group clause returns a sequence of IGrouping objects that contain zero or more items that match the key value for the group*

so if you wanted a group returned your code might look like this:

```
var o = (
        from ord in sampleOrders
        group ord by ord.Product  // Should return a group.
```

Since you're using the `into` the keyword, you're going to get an order object because you used the' `select` keyword .

Comment: No, the order is because of the second `from`, which is doing a `SelectMany`, effectively. (Look at Servy's answer - there's still a select, but the result is a sequence of groups rather than a sequence of orders...)